# How to only update a field if it's different in mongodb so that watch() isn't called

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB's stream changes `watch()` function to check for changes in the database but it's returning an update change even if the value hasn't changed

I have the following document:

```
{
     test: "abc"
}
```

if I use:

```
Price.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
         test: "abc"
    },
    {
         test: "abc"
    }
);
```

Then `watch()` is called even though `test` hasn't actually changed.  Is there a way to only change the value in MongoDB if it is different?

For reference, here is my watch() code:

```
Price.watch([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {"updateDescription.updatedFields.test": {$exists: true}}
            ],
            operationType: {$in: ["replace", "insert", "update"]}
        }
    }
],
{fullDocument: "updateLookup"}
).on("change", change => {
    const {fullDocument} = change;
    if (io) {
        io.to(fullDocument.userID.toString()).emit("price", fullDocument);
    }
});
```

I'm wondering if it's because I have timestamps enabled and the `updateAt` field is changed?  This is how I define the schema:

```
const Price = new Schema(
    {
        userID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true},
        test: String
    },
    {timestamps: true}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `watch` method will only return entries that have been written to the oplog, and committed to a majority of the replica set.

If an `update` does not make any changes to any field in a matched document, nothing is written, so there is no oplog entry, nothing replicated to the secondary nodes, and nothing for `watch` to return.

It is indeed the timestamps being update that causes the document to be different, and require an oplog entry which is returned by `watch`. As you noted, the `test` field was not present in the `updatedFields` of the watch response, because it was not actually updated.

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense.  The only issue is, the `test` field is also returned even though it didn't change.  I'm guessing `updateDescription.updatedFields` includes all fields in the update even though only one of the fields changed, right?  Is there any way to know which fields actually changed?